# Display console logs in an application

Tags: java, swing, console, jframe, jbutton

I just created a simple logic that generates a number between 1 to 100. If it's an even number, it prints out "Heads", and if it's an odd number, it prints out "Tails" in the console.

Then I also added a button using `Jbutton` and `Jframe`. I got a start game button in a separate window application when I execute the code, but how can I make the game logic display inside the window application instead of in the console?

Imagine right now when I execute the code, a little window with a "start game" button pops up, I have to drag that window to the right, then click it and the game logic begin in the console (which I have to look at my IDE to see what's printing out).

The code for the game logic:

```java
package com.headOrTails;

import java.util.*;

public class GameLogic {
    public void gameLogicFunction() { // Generate random number and if it is an odd number prints head, else tails

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        long randomNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 100);

        boolean isPlaying = true;
        String userContinue;

        do{

            if (randomNumber % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Heads");
                System.out.println("And btw the number was " + randomNumber);

            } else {
                System.out.println("Tails");
                System.out.println("And btw the number was " + randomNumber);
            }

            System.out.println("Do you want to conitnue? y or n");
            userContinue = input.next();

        } while (userContinue.equals("y") || userContinue.equals("Y"));
    }
}
```

And the code for the frame that comes up is:

```java
package com.headOrTails;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    // init game logic class
    GameLogic game1 = new GameLogic();

    MyFrame() {

        // Init button and design it
        JButton button = new JButton(); // init button
        button.setBounds(200,100,100,50);
        button.addActionListener(e -> game1.gameLogicFunction()); // use lambda expression to run game logic
        button.setText("Start game");

        // create and size the application window
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(500,500);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(button);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html

Comment: Instead of printing in the console, you can put the text in a TextArea component, as mentioned above.

Comment: Great, worked perfectly. Had no idea about this TextArea component.

Comment: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) Be sure to use a `JTextArea`, not a `TextArea`.